# Dynamic Google Charts binded with Date fields

Tags: google-visualization

Need some tips on how to embed the Calendar controls like From Date and To Date in Google Charts and chart values are changed according to chosen date. The charts will refresh when the button is clicked.

Below is the code which I am using to display multiple charts on single page where data is fetched from the database in JSON.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    <!--

    // Load the Visualization API and the piechart package.
    google.load('visualization', '1', {'packages':['corechart']});

    // Set a callback to run when the Google Visualization API is loaded.    
    google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

    function drawChart()
    {

    // set the default options
        var options =   {
                            width: "100%",
                            height: 350, 
                            chartArea: {left:50,top:20,width:"70%",height:"70%"},
                            legend: {position: 'bottom'},
                            vAxis: {title: "" },
                            hAxis: {title: "No.of Jobs"},
                            is3D: false
                        };

    // 1st Chart-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
        var jsonData = $.ajax({
            url: "jsondata.asp?q=json_construct.asp&id=FK_IssuedByDeptID",
            dataType:"json",
            async: false
                            }).responseText;


        // Create our data table out of JSON data loaded from server.
        var data = new google.visualization.DataTable(jsonData);

        var chart1  =   new google.visualization.BarChart(document.getElementById('chart_OpenByFunction'));
        chart1.draw(data, options);

    // 2nd Chart----------------------------------------------------------------------------

        var jsonData = $.ajax({
            url: "jsondata.asp?q=json_construct.asp&id=FK_IssuedToDeptID",
            dataType:"json",
            async: false
                            }).responseText;

        // Create our data table out of JSON data loaded from server.
        var data = new google.visualization.DataTable(jsonData);

        var chart2  =   new google.visualization.BarChart(document.getElementById('chart_OpenToFunction'));
        chart2.draw(data, options);

    // 3rd Chart----------------------------------------------------------------------------

        var jsonData = $.ajax({
            url: "jsondata.asp?q=json_construct_status.asp&id=''",
            dataType:"json",
            async: false
                            }).responseText;

        // Create our data table out of JSON data loaded from server.
        var data = new google.visualization.DataTable(jsonData);

        var chart3  =   new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('chart_OpenByStatus'));
        chart3.draw(data, options);

    // 4th Chart----------------------------------------------------------------------------

        var jsonData = $.ajax({
            url: "jsondata.asp?q=json_reject_reasons.asp&id=''",
            dataType:"json",
            async: false
                            }).responseText;

        // Create our data table out of JSON data loaded from server.
        var data = new google.visualization.DataTable(jsonData);

        var chart4  =   new google.visualization.BarChart(document.getElementById('chart_OpenByReason'));
        chart4.draw(data, options);     


        // 5th Chart----------------------------------------------------------------------------

        var jsonData = $.ajax({
            url: "jsondata.asp?q=json_pack_type.asp&id=''",
            dataType:"json",
            async: false
                            }).responseText;

        // Create our data table out of JSON data loaded from server.
        var data = new google.visualization.DataTable(jsonData);

        var chart5  =   new google.visualization.BarChart(document.getElementById('chart_OpenByPackType'));
        chart5.draw(data, options);

    } 
</script>
```

Appreciate your help.

Comment: Are you trying to get the chart package to change its time axis? Where's your data from? Wouldn't it be better to change whatever query you use to get the data so you're only getting data for the required period? Or am I misunderstanding your problem?

Comment: Jamie, the data shown in the charts will be coming from database using JSON (as stated in the question) and that part is working perfectly fine. The need is to apply the dates so that user can narrow the chart results.

Comment: Can't you limit the results coming from the database though?

Comment: @Jamie: While displaying the results on page load, the data is already filtered based on a week but is user wants to see graphs based on the date range selected then I need to have the dropdowns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to come up with an alternative to achieve the required output. The solution which I applied is

1. Created frameset in HTML where the 1st frame shows the DatePicker controls
2. The value submitted is captured by the 2nd frame file and pass the dates as a parameter to GoogleChart URL.

   var jsonData = $.ajax({url: "jsondata.asp?q=json_construct.asp&id=FK_IssuedByDeptID&fdt='<%=fromDate%>'&tdt='<%=toDate%>'", dataType:"json", async: false}).responseText;